# Was I correct to edit this question based on my understanding of it?

Tags: discussion, edits

Recently I was on a process of reviewing all my old answers which had very less attention (obviously by the vote count on question + answer) to see if there was anyway that I could improve either/both of them so that they would better help the community and came across the below mentioned question.

[Hide the validation output mark (✘) symbol hide when page is loaded/reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964904/hide-the-validation-output-mark-%E2%9C%98-symbol-hide-when-page-is-loaded-reloaded)

Before my edit, the question (and the title) was very vaguely explained as an one-liner and was not very clear. I think part of that is to do with the OP's minimal English expertise (as they themselves had admitted in their now deleted answer-comment). Based on my understanding, I felt that the question was a reasonably good one though not great (and could actually even be a duplicate). So, I proceeded to edit the question and title to add some more meaningful description to it and I felt pretty confident that I was doing it the correct way.

However, after me editing the question it has received a further down-vote which makes me wonder if I really did the correct thing by editing the question and am looking for some community feedback. I am not looking for votes on my answer and my question is more about whether the my edit has made the question at-least a bit more useful for the community on the whole or not.

Comment: I think the second downvote was just random, due to the fact that the edit bumped the question to the question list and someone happened to not like your question for whatever reason. Your edit is definitely good though, the previous revision of the question was quite unclear.

Comment: I am extremely happy to note the response to my edit with the question now being in the positive. Thanks to all those who have taken the effort to evaluate. @AndréDaniel: Would you like to add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it accepted mate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit was good and changed the question from "I want to do x please give me teh codez" into something better that can be understood without reading the code (which I personally wouldn't bother doing if the OP can't bother explaining what he wants).

The unfortunate downvote you got after the edit was just random, the wrong man in the wrong place at the wrong time happened to not like that particular question and downvoted it.